# Play 2.4 (Java) - Access session in the validate method

Tags: java, session, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm working on a password change model where I have three fields

- Current password
- New password
- Confirm new password

In my validate() method of the model, I want to be able to get the logged in user via the session scope so that I can check that the current password is valid. Is there any way to get session? Or maybe there is a better and more secure way to implement this?

```
public String validate(){

    //Check if current password is valid

    if (newPassword == null || !newPassword.equals(newPasswordConfirm)) {
        return "New passwords do not match";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The session is available in the controller layer. If this method is in your model, you need to pass what you need in the session (i.e. : userId) to the validate method as parameter. You need to decouple things. Don't try to pass the session to your model.

Comment: Makes sense, I have done it like that now. That is NOT pass the session

Comment: @c4k If you submit it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is available in the controller layer. If this method is in your model, you need to pass what you need in the session (i.e. : userId) to the validate method as parameter. You need to decouple things. Don't try to pass the session to your model.